# Does Kubernetes always use a single image for deployments?

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes

I have the following for one of my deployment files:

```
  containers:
  - name: ouroboros 
    image: [my-user]/ouroboros
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

I want other teammates to be able to develop locally on `minikube`, but it seems like the image that's used is set in stone. I have a small shell script that uses `sed` to replace `[my-user]` with another DockerHub profile, but that still seems like a weird way to allow multiple people to work on our services locally.

Are there any alternative configs I can use for deciding which Docker image to use locally?

Comment: Can you run local registries instead of pushing all builds out to dockerhub? Then everyone can share a `local` prefix

Comment: You could have a look at [helm](https://helm.sh/). It is a k8s package manager with templating capabilites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command, your local docker dommand will be actualy run on the docker that is powering minikube. That means that if you use `pullPolicy: if NotPresent` and set that env, you can use `docker build` to update that image to a localy built development version (with `pullPolicy: Always` it would still pull from docker hub).